# Why is my directory search taking so long?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, directoryservices, directorysearcher

I've been troubleshooting performance in a REST API I've built that, among other things, returns a list of users from Active Directory based on a search term that is provided. Based on some logging that I've built in for test purposes, I can see that the whole process of fetching the settings (e.g. LDAP search information) and retrieving all of the search results takes less than a second:

```
30/08/2017 3:37:58 PM | Getting search results.
30/08/2017 3:37:58 PM | Retrieving default settings
30/08/2017 3:37:58 PM | Default settings retrieved. Creating directoryEntry
30/08/2017 3:37:58 PM | Search retrieved.
30/08/2017 3:37:58 PM | Iterating through search results.
30/08/2017 3:38:16 PM | Search results iteration complete.
```

However, as you can see iterating through these search results and populating my list of users is taking 18 seconds. This is my code:

```
SearchResultCollection resultList = new DirectorySearcher(CreateDirectoryEntry())
{
    Filter = ("(&(objectClass=user) (cn=*" + SearchTerm + "*))"),
    PropertiesToLoad =
    {
        "givenName",
        "sn",
        "sAMAccountName",
        "mail"
    }
}.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult result in resultList)
{
    ADUser thisUser = new ADUser();

    try
    {
        thisUser.Firstname = result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        thisUser.Firstname = "Firstname not found";
    }
    try
    {
        thisUser.Lastname = result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        thisUser.Lastname = "Lastname not found";
    }
    try
    {
        thisUser.EmailAddress = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        thisUser.EmailAddress = "Email address not found";
    }

    UserList.Add(thisUser);
}
```

It's pretty vanilla and not doing anything fancy. Any idea why this would be so slow, or any suggestions as to what I could do differently to speed this up?

**UPDATE**

Based on comments and answers I have removed the null checking from the code. So now it looks like this:

```
foreach (SearchResult result in resultList)
{
    ADUser thisUser = new ADUser();

    thisUser.Firstname = result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
    thisUser.Lastname = result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
    thisUser.EmailAddress = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();

    UserList.Add(thisUser);
}
```

This has not improved the performance. I can see this loop is still taking around 18 seconds, even when there is only one result returned. (It's also demonstrated that crappy data in my AD means I need this null check!)

Comment: what if you will do if(result.Properties["givenName"][0] != null)

Comment: if it's null enter your "exception" message without try,catch and so on

Comment: is SearchResult a `System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult` or is it your own custom type? if it is the framwork type, please update your question to show how you build your `DirectorySearcher` object.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I believe SearchResult is lazy loaded, and it is most likely that he uses the type you referred.

Comment: @GhasanAl-Sakkaf i agree, if the OP did not include the columns he is checking information for to the `DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad` collection each request will require a round trip to the AD server due to the lazy loading.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes I'm using the default type and yes I have already restricted the PropertiesToLoad. Updating Q now.

Comment: @GhasanAl-Sakkaf as per my comment to Scott...

Comment: What is returned by `CreateDirectoryEntry()`?  If you explicitly specify to connect to a local domain controller by setting the `searchRoot` parameter/`SearchRoot` property of your `DirectorySearcher` to something like `"LDAP://" + dcIPOrName` does that improve anything?

Comment: @BACON I've set the searchRoot to a specific OU I'm searching for results from. What's dcIPOrName?

Comment: @MattG `dcIPOrName` would be a variable containing the IP address or host name of a domain controller to connect to.  My point is to ensure that the search is being performed by a domain controller on your local network and not one on the other side of the planet (not knowing what your forest looks like).  Also, perhaps a Wireshark packet capture would give some insights into why the query is taking so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are relying on exceptions when setting the properties of `thisUser` when, depending on your directory, it might not be all that *exceptional* for a user to not have their `givenName`, `sn`, and/or `mail` attributes populated.  If you have a long list of search results all these exceptions can add up.  Consider checking if the desired property exists instead of using `try`/`catch` blocks:

```
thisUser.Firstname = result.Properties.Contains("givenName")
    ? result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString()
    : "Firstname not found";
thisUser.Lastname = result.Properties.Contains("sn")
    ? result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString()
    : "Lastname not found";
thisUser.EmailAddress = result.Properties.Contains("mail")
    ? result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString()
    : "Email address not found";
```

You can use the [null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) from C# 6 with the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) to simplify this to the following:

```
thisUser.Firstname = result.Properties["givenName"]?[0]?.ToString() ?? "Firstname not found";
thisUser.Lastname = result.Properties["sn"]?[0]?.ToString() ?? "Lastname not found";
thisUser.EmailAddress = result.Properties["mail"]?[0]?.ToString() ?? "Email address not found";
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've removed all of the error checking from the code altogether and confirmed it does not have a significant impact on performance. Updating question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, this is much more elegant than the cack-handed way I did it, so thanks! I'll be incorporating this for the null check when I get past the performance issue.

Comment: Marking as answer. Performance is now vastly improved (<1s). The null-conditional operator took as long as the try/catch, but using the first method you've suggested seems to have nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like that:

```
foreach (SearchResult result in resultList)
            {
                ADUser thisUser = new ADUser();
                if(result.Properties["givenName"][0] != null)
                    thisUser.Firstname = result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
                else
                    thisUser.Firstname = "Firstname not found";

                if(thisUser.Lastname = result.Properties["sn"][0] != null)
                    thisUser.Lastname = result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
                else
                    thisUser.Lastname = "Lastname not found";

                if(result.Properties["mail"][0] != null)
                    thisUser.EmailAddress = result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
                else
                    thisUser.EmailAddress = "Email address not found";

                UserList.Add(thisUser);
            }
```